# How to change the button size in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

In this Menu i want to change the button size, i tried some code but its not working. What change i need to do for the below code to change the height and width of the button?

[image]

```
listeners: {
            afterrender: function () {
                var menu = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')[0].headerCt.getMenu();
                menu.add([{
                    text: 'Search',
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home',
                    handler: function () {
                        console.log("Search Item");
                    }
                },{ 
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel : 'Filter By',
            width: 300,
            height: 20          
          },{

          xtype: 'button',
          fieldLabel : 'Filter By',
          text : 'Ok',
          width: 15,
          height:25,
          maxLength: 10,
          enableToggle: true
          } ,{

          xtype: 'button',
          text : 'Cancel',
          width: 15,
          height:25,
          maxLength: 10,
          enableToggle: true
          }


          ]);



            }
        }
```

Comment: Give fiddle and show same

Comment: @Tejas1991 [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27qc)

Comment: What height you want for button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27qe

It seems that button is not taking width config, so I replaced it with **maxWidth**, which worked.But I didnt face height issue for button as button was taking height which was specified in its config.
Check given fiddle for running code.Reply if any concerns.

Comment: 1991 Thank you very much for spending ur valuable time..It works fine. I want to keep the two button in a straight row, what i need to do for that?

Comment: Straight row means one after the other ?

Comment: yeah like that only

Comment: Check fiddle now. I have aligned both buttons.